# maven assembly plugin: how to exclude resource from the jar mentioned in dependencies

Tags: jar, resources, external

While creating assembly (unpacked big jar), I need to exclude a resource from the jar mentioned in dependencies. I may exclude specific jars, but is it possible to exclude resources from that jars?

Answer (score 0):

This option helps:

```
<unpack>true</unpack>
            <unpackOptions>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/activators/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </unpackOptions>
```